# How to resize a ubuntu partition to make more room for windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, disk-space

My laptop has Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 installed alongside each other. My laptop has two 225GB hard drives. I give Ubuntu 133.65GB and I give Windows 87.76GB on the same hard drive (C).

My problem now is that Windows is almost out of space but Ubuntu is only using a few GB of the 133.65GB that I gave it. I want to reduce Ubuntu's partition size and give that space to increase Windows partition size.

Is that any program that can to do this?

Comment: If you have them in partitions in the same disk, then what you need is a disk management utility that can resize/move the partitions without losing the data. I think GParted, a linux utility, could do that. Search here or over at askubuntu.com for "resize partition". (as usual a backup is recomended)

Answer (score 1):

GParted can do this easily. (http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php)

I am assuming Ubuntu is first and Windows is 2nd but if it is the opposite the procedure is more or less the same.

- download the ISO
- burn the ISO to a CD
- boot the CD
- choose all default options for GParted
- select the correct hard drive that has both Ubuntu and Windows partition
- choose the action to shrink the Ubuntu partition from the right end of it
- hit apply and wait for GParted to unallocate that region
- now move the Windows partition to the left filling the unallocated space
- hit apply and wait for GParted to move the windows partition
- choose action to re-size the Windows partition and expand it to the end of the drive
- apply changes when you are happy
- reboot

Additional references:

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual

http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

Comment: Not so easy peasy...If the concerned sectors contain data then things can turn nasty...

Comment: GParted handles that or complains from my experience but your right. I haven't had issues doing this in the past and if his Ubuntu drive is only using a few GB out of 100+ then the 2nd half of that partition is probably fine.

Comment: AFAIK, unless he is using a GPT/RAID(I doubt that), partitions need to be continuous on a disk....I mean you cant just select bunches of clusters on disk and make a partition out of them... So layout on disk cant be like [half of windows partition][linux partition][other half of windows partition]..

Comment: If it is set up: [-----------ubuntu---------70%][---windows---30%] you can shrink the ubuntu to 50% freeing up 20% that then becomes unallocated. After that you can move the existing windows partition into the unallocated region filling up the space and then re-size the windows partition to extend it into the unallocated space at the end (I forgot the move part in my answer).

Comment: Your example would yield a main partition (C) for windows and a separate partition (D) and is not what the OP is likely looking for but could be done. You are right that you cannot select separate partitions and make one drive letter out of it unless you use a dynamic disk set up or something similar.